# which database accecpt object

Tags: java, database

```
 I want to know which all databases allow object insertion directly.
```

Means, in mongoDB we can directly insert object. save(class_object). like this which all databases allow object insertion

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a list, which might become out of date almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

To aid you in your search, there are at least three **types** of databases that support inserting objects "directly" (if you give them some wiggle room over the meaning of "directly"):

1. **Object-oriented databases** - these are complex and support arbitrary 
   object graphs, which can be as huge as your hardware's storage capacity. However, few people actually use them!
2. **Document databases** - these are simpler than so-called "object-oriented databases", in that they just work with documents, which may or may not represent objects, e.g. in JSON form.
3. **XML databases** - note that some relational databases such as Oracle also have XML features.

However, I will point out that your question is misleading - just because a database stores objects "directly", does not mean that it is necessarily "better" for storing objects. After all, object-relational mapping tools exist for relational databases. What is better for you would depend on your requirements.

Also, if you really wanted to, you could store objects directly in a relational database, serialized in blobs using e.g. JSON or XML. Some databases even have special support for querying XML, as hinted above.

Answer (score 1):

If your object is [serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html), the answer is, any database will accept it.

Comment: Java binary object serialization is *not* recommended for long-term storage!!